macOS menu bar - How to put a checkmark next to currently selected submenu item
I am putting in a menu in my app where there are various sub menus.
To simplify things let's just say the variable selected exists and this shows the selected option. Likewise the variable menuItems exists and is a string array with the menu items.
The real code is a bit more complex but works fine. I just can't get checkmarks to display the way they do in native macOS app menus (e.g. The Edit > Spelling and Grammar menu in Vivaldi, which has a list of options a a checkmark on selected ones on the left, and all the items line up horizontally so there is space on the left of options which don't have a checkmark).
To be clear: only one menu item should be selected at a time, so the toggle method that is elsewhere here on SO  will not work.
Here is the code example:
CommandMenu ("Settings") {
    Menu("Sub Menu") {
        ForEach (menuItems, id: \.offset) { item in
            Button (item, action: {
              ...
            })
        }
    }
}

I have tried a bunch of different ways, using the system image "checkmark":

Image and Text with conditional opacity in an HStack -> doesn't work: SwiftUl ignores styling in menu items.
Image, Spacer and Text in an HStack with a condition that only displays the Image if the current option is selected, with the checkmark in front like native apps -> Menu items are not aligned properly
Image, Spacer and Text with a condition that only displays the Image if the current option is selected, with the checkmark at the end. -> Menu items are not aligned properly
Label using the text and the icon. -> doesn't work at all

I went to the Apple Developer Menu docs here. It doesn't have anything about what it calls "menu identifiers" in submenus.
Does anyone know the correct way to do this?
Update: Based on answers I got that don't simply translate to what I'm doing (no surprise there), this is my entire main App file:
I got all kinds of different errors that are just too much to name here when trying to apply the answers to my code in various ways (trying to fix what the errors said was the problem)
import SwiftUI

@main
struct SimpleTrackerApp: App {
    @State var viewModel = ViewModel()
        
    func resetTracker() {
        viewModel.resetBosses()
        viewModel.resetItems()
    }

    struct settingsMenu: View {
        @Environment(ViewModel.self) private var viewModel
        
        var body: some View {
            ForEach(Array(viewModel.seedOptions.enumerated()), id: \.key) { index in
                Picker(viewModel.seedOptions[index].title, selection: $viewModel.seedOptions[index].selection) {
                    ForEach(Array(viewModel.seedOptions[index].options.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { offset, option in
                        Button(option) {}
                            .tag(offset)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environment(viewModel)
        }
        .defaultSize(width: 857, height: 468)
        .commands {
            CommandGroup(replacing: .newItem) {
                Button("Reset Tracker") {
                    resetTracker()
                }
                .keyboardShortcut("R", modifiers: [.command])
            }
            CommandMenu("Settings") {
                settingsMenu()
                    .environment(viewModel)
            }
        }
    }
}

I take full responsibility for this mistake of thinking that an answer to the simplified example would apply to my more complex code.

You could use a nested Picker as the sub-menu.
You will need to have a state variable to store the selection, and the tags for the picker items need to have the same type as the state variable. The index position of the items could be used here. By using an optional, it can start unselected:
@State private var selection: Int?

If you use an enumeration of the array in the ForEach then the closure receives the index and the string item (see this answer for a detailed explanation of how this works):
CommandMenu("Settings") {
    Picker("Sub Menu", selection: $selection) {
        ForEach(Array(menuItems.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { offset, item in
            Button(item) {}
                .tag(offset)
        }
    }
}



EDIT Following from your comments, this is how I think you can use a computed property as a wrapper for a published property in the model. I have never done it that way before, but it seems to work.
class MyViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published private var selection: Int?

    var selectedOption: Int? {
        get { selection }
        set { selection = newValue }
    }
}

Picker("Sub Menu", selection: $viewModel.selectedOption) {
    // ...
}


Is there a way to do this if the actual variable that holds the selection is in an Observable class whose "selection" is private and has an update() method that updates it?

I am getting a thousand errors with this, 560 characters are not enough to type out everything I tried to get this to work with my code and the errors each thing got.
Instead of beating a dead horse and complaining I will simply say: I have a array of instances of class SeeddOptions of which one of the properties is options which is the array of strings in order that they should appear, and selection which is the selection. So: viewModel.seedOptions[i].options & viewModel.seedOptions[i].selection

This is an Observable class, and it's being used in the main App struct. I put .environment(viewModel) under the separate view I have this code in (I separated it from the .comman in the main view due to the "compiler cannot type-check code in a reasonable time" error, and '@Environment(ViewModel.self) private var viewModel' outside the body of the view.

I updated the question with the entire App code.

@Alex The Picker requires a binding to the variable that stores the selection. Instead of using a local state variable (as in the answer), you could most certainly use a published property in an observable object. If the variable is visible outside the model then the syntax is $viewModel.selection, see SwiftUI ViewModel published property and binding. If you want to keep the published variable private then I guess you could provide a computed property for it, answer updated to show how.

One way to solve this is to change the type of menuItems into an enum
enum MenuItem: String, CaseIterable {
    case oneItem = "Item One"
    case ...¨
}

and then use a Picker directly in your top menu
CommandMenu ("Settings") {
    Picker("Sub Menu", selection: $selectedSubMenu) {
        ForEach(MenuItem.allCases, id: \.self) {
            Text($0.rawValue)
                 .tag($0)
        }
    }
}


I don't know if this will work because they have to be in the same order every time.

As far as I know allCases will always return the elements in the order they are declared in the enum and then you have the option to add your own custom sorting.

In my specific situation apparently you can't just use a binding the way you normally would by putting a $ in front of the variable.
The solution turns out to be completely different.
You have to create a binding manually.
This is the settingsMenu changes that solve the problem and work perfectly:
My SeedOption class also has an update() method which is what updates the actual value..
Anyone having the same thing where you use a setter to set the value where it is not desirable to directly change the value itself, you can do it this way.
This creates a manual binding and you can explicitly set the getter and setter to work for your situation.
    struct settingsMenu: View {
        @Environment(ViewModel.self) private var viewModel
        
        var body: some View {
            ForEach(viewModel.seedOptions, id: \.key) { seedOption in
                Picker(seedOption.title, selection: Binding(
                    get: { seedOption.selection },
                    set: { seedOption.update($0) })) {
                    ForEach(Array(seedOption.options.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { index, option in
                        Text(option)
                            .tag(index) // Use 'index' as the tag if you're selecting by index
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

